# I am trying to produce a graph that updates in real time and I am getting the output: <Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I am trying to mimic the results of a tutorial on matplotlib. I am working in the OS environment. As near as I can tell I am using an exact replica of the code from the tutorial aside from changing the name of the csv file to avoid an overwrite.

The code used to create and update the CSV is:

```
import csv
import random
import time

x_value = 0
total_1 = 1000
total_2 = 1000

fieldnames = ["x_value", "total_1", "total_2"]


with open('real_time_data.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_writer.writeheader()

while True:

    with open('real_time_data.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

        info = {
            "x_value": x_value,
            "total_1": total_1,
            "total_2": total_2
        }

        csv_writer.writerow(info)
        print(x_value, total_1, total_2)

        x_value += 1
        total_1 = total_1 + random.randint(-6, 8)
        total_2 = total_2 + random.randint(-5, 6)

    time.sleep(1)
```

The code I used to read the CSV and create and update the graph is:

```
import random
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

index = count()


def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv('real_time_data.csv')
    x = data['x_value']
    y1 = data['total_1']
    y2 = data['total_2']

    plt.cla()

    plt.plot(x, y1, label='Channel 1')
    plt.plot(x, y2, label='Channel 2')

    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.tight_layout()


ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval=1000)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Instead of a graph I get: Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes.
I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should add *%matplotlib inline* or *%matplotlib qt* before importing matplotlib